# Returning a value from Perl script to a java Form

Tags: java, perl

I call a Perl script from java using :

```
{
  Process process;
  process= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl readoldVersionFromFile.pl ");
}
```

the value returned from the Perl script is a string that should be used to set the text of a textField in the java form.

My Approach :
in the Perl script I print the value to be returned

```
{
  print $cfile;
   }
```

in java i get the output stream of the process :

```
{ 
  out = process.getOutputStream();
 }
```

Now my problem is i am not able to get the string from variable out.
Is there any other way to do this.

Comment: did you try getting it by process.getInputStream() ?

Comment: i did this :  { InputStream in=process.getInputStream(); in.read(byteVar); system.out.println(byteVar.toString());}  but this only prints the internal representation of byteVar.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream%28%29)

public abstract OutputStream getOutputStream();

This method return a OutputStream, how can you read from an OutputStream? The method returns the output stream connected to the normal input of the subprocess. Output to the stream is piped into the standard input of the process represented by the Process object.

You should try the [Process#getInputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream%28%29)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Since I have to pass only a variable, I am now doing this by storing and reading from a temp text file. I delete this file after reading.